# The right way to implement pressed button effect in CSS

Tags: css, grid

I am creating piano layout using CSS.
I really like this "button-pressed" effect, but it shifts elements around it. How does one avoid it?

```html
<main>
    <div id="o-2" class="octave">
        <button id="C2" class="C key"></button>
        <button id="C2-sharp" class="C-sharp key-black"></button>
        <button id="D2" class="D key"></button>
        <button id="D2-sharp" class="D-sharp key-black"></button>
        <button id="E2" class="E key"></button>
    </div>
</main>
```

```css
main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.octave {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(14, auto);
}

button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 1px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black;
}
```

Positioning of keys are implemented using grid.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `transform` property instead of adjusting the `margin` in the :`active` pseudo-class. The `transform` property allows you to scale the button slightly and move it down when it is pressed, without affecting the layout of surrounding elements.

```
...
button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease; /* Add a smooth transition */
}

button:active {
  transform: scale(0.95) translateY(3px); /* Scale down and move down */
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the button element type. I share it below.

```css
main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.octave {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(14, auto);
}

a {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 1px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:14px;
    height:30px;
}

a:active {
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div id="o-2" class="octave">
        <a id="C2" class="C key"></a>
        <a id="C2-sharp" class="C-sharp key-black"></a>
        <a id="D2" class="D key"></a>
        <a id="D2-sharp" class="D-sharp key-black"></a>
        <a id="E2" class="E key"></a>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me in both Safari and Chrome. Other buttons still shift

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
button:active{
   transform: translate(4px, 4px);
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the "button-pressed" effect is shifting the elements around it is because you're adding margins to the button when it's active. One way to avoid this is to use transform: translate() instead of margins to move the button when it's pressed. This way, the button will still take up the same amount of space as before, and the other elements won't be affected.

Here's an example of how you can modify your CSS to use transform instead of margins:

```css
button:active {
    transform: translate(4px, 4px);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black;
}
```

In this code, we're using the transform property to move the button 4 pixels to the right and 4 pixels down when it's pressed. The box-shadow property is also modified to make the button look more like it's pressed.